# Running spark.sql as part of a job in job cluster in Databricks dbx

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, databricks-sql

Does anyone know how to run spark.sql commands in Python script in dbx in a job cluster? Somehow my code works on a Personal Compute cluster but failed on a Job Cluster. I am guessing it is the JDBC settings, but it seems like there is no way to specify JDBC settings on a Job Cluster.

Below are the SQL commands I am trying to execute. I did it in OOP format as prescribed in dbx. The location is a random location in Azure Blob Storage mounted to DBFS.

I was attempting to write a Spark Dataframe in Pyspark to be inserted into a Delta table.

```
self.spark.sql(
f"""
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS solis
LOCATION '{self.metadata_db_path}'
"""
)

self.spark.sql(
f"""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS solis.metadata (
   imagekey STRING, StdImgDate STRING, StdImgView STRING,
   StdProdID STRING, StdVisit STRING, Study STRING, RowKey STRING, 
   ProcessedTimestamp LONG
) USING DELTA LOCATION '{self.metadata_db_path}'
PARTITIONED BY (Study)
"""
```

But it was able to create the schema but it was not able to create the table. It keeps producing the following error.

```
AzureBlobFileSystemStore: Received exception while listing a directory.
Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404
```

I figured that it was the JDBC settings, because I was able to execute it on an interactive cluster using `dbx execute`, but it would always fail on a job cluster.

[image]

So how am I able to run SQL query in a job cluster?

Comment: You can add an Answer and mark as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: I was mistaken. My solution did not solve the problem. I am still facing the same issues. Therefore I have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to ensure there is minimum 1 worker node.

Otherwise, when it is performed in a single node, the following spark configuration has to be specified.

```
spark.databricks.cluster.profile singleNode
spark.master local[*, 4]
```